# Exporting to Excel (OpenXML) results in Unreadable Content

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I've been struggeling with creating worksheets for my xlsx file. Adding the first worksheet isn't a problem, but when I want a second sheet, the exported xlsx seems to be corrupt. Who can point out to me what I'm doing wrong?
Note: I already tried to also call 'workbookpart,Workbook.Save();' right after creating the first Workbook, but without the required result.

```
protected void export_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ExportToExcel(@"D:\dev\Dotnet4\Excel\test.xlsx");
}

private void ExportToExcel(string filepath)
{
    SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument;
    WorkbookPart workbookpart;
    CreateSpreadsheet(filepath, out spreadsheetDocument, out workbookpart);

    CreateWorksheet(spreadsheetDocument, workbookpart, "My sheet 1");
    CreateWorksheet(spreadsheetDocument, workbookpart, "My sheet 2");

    workbookpart.Workbook.Save();

    // Close the document.
    spreadsheetDocument.Close();
}

private static void CreateWorksheet(SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument, WorkbookPart workbookpart, string worksheetName)
{
    // Add a WorksheetPart to the WorkbookPart.
    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookpart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
    worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());

    // Add Sheets to the Workbook.
    Sheets sheets = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.
        AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());

    // Append a new worksheet and associate it with the workbook.
    Sheet sheet = new Sheet()
    {
        Id = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.
            GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart),
        SheetId = 1,
        Name = worksheetName
    };
    sheets.Append(sheet);
}

private static void CreateSpreadsheet(string filepath, out SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument, out WorkbookPart workbookpart)
{
    // Create a spreadsheet document by supplying the filepath.
    // By default, AutoSave = true, Editable = true, and Type = xlsx.
    spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.
        Create(filepath, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);

    // Add a WorkbookPart to the document.
    workbookpart = spreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart();
    workbookpart.Workbook = new Workbook();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have 2 small issues:

1. The `SheetId` is the same for both sheets you are adding which is invalid.
2. You are adding a new `Sheets` element each time you call `CreateWorksheet` but there should only be one such element in the XML (there are many `Sheet`'s but not many `Sheets`!).

To solve 1 you could use the count of the `sheets.ChildElements`. As this is `0` first time round and one the second you'll need to add `1` to it. If you prefer you could take it in to `CreateWorksheet` as a parameter; it doesn't really matter as long as they start at 1 and are different.

To solve 2 you can perform a null check on the `Sheets` property of the `Workbook` and only create it if it doesn't already exist.

The below should do what you're after.

```
private static void CreateWorksheet(SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument, WorkbookPart workbookpart, string worksheetName)
{
    // Add a WorksheetPart to the WorkbookPart.
    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookpart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
    worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());

    // Add Sheets to the Workbook.
    if (spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets == null)
    {
        //spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets = new Sheets();
        spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook
                                        .AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());
    }

    Sheets sheets = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets;

    // Append a new worksheet and associate it with the workbook.
    Sheet sheet = new Sheet()
    {
        Id = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.
            GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart),
        SheetId = (UInt32)sheets.ChildElements.Count + 1,
        Name = worksheetName
    };
    sheets.Append(sheet);
}
```

One final point is that `SpreadsheetDocument` implements `IDisposable` so it should be disposed after use.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Your first note I also found just a few moments after posting. The second issue you noted seemed to be the problem indeed. After fixing, this worked like a charm.