# OpenXml Word document - Found unreadable content in file

Tags: c#, .net, openxml, openxml-sdk

Is there any option how to find exactly the right place where is unreadable part in Word OpenXml located? I mean the right place in inner document.xml.

Programatically or with any tool. I am using OpenXml SDK 2.5.
[image]

Comment: A lot of issues like this can be found using the [OpenXml Productivity Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30425) such as the one in my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25398450/why-appending-autofilter-corrupts-my-excel-file-in-this-example/25410242#25410242). The tool is (presumably) using XML validation so not all errors are caught by it (for example, the first issue in my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253320/exporting-to-excel-openxml-results-in-unreadable-content/26256310#26256310)).

Comment: Thanks for answer, but not any from your previous answers solve my problem. Also OpenXml Produktivity Tool. I used it befor my question and validation did not show me any error. I mean that in document, there is something what should be not there and Word don't know what to do with it. And I cannot find it.

Comment: In that case the XML is most likely valid but some of your values aren't. You'll need to look for duplicate Ids, values out of range and that kind of thing. Without seeing the code that generates the file with the error or seeing the file itself I doubt anyone would be able to help you.

Comment: Allow Word to recover the content then save that document to a different name. Open the original ("bad") document in the Productivity Tool then use the ***compare*** feature to compare the repaired document to the original. You can see where the Open XML is different as well as the code required to create the repaired document from the original your current code is generating. That should tell you where the problem(s) come(s) from.